# Job search while on probation - what to keep in mind?

Tags: job-search, germany, probation

I recently started a new job and quickly realized that the employer somewhat oversold themselves and their "culture" in the interviews.

I know that the first few weeks can be frustrating, so I'm going to give this new job a chance. After all, the **probation period is 6 months**, so I have plenty of time to make a decision. At the same time, I'd like to be prepared for the eventuality of picking up my job search again.

**Is there anything I need to be aware of when applying elsewhere while I'm still under probation with my current employer?**

Some additional comments:

In related questions I've seen the recommendation to quit early and not even mention the short stint on your resume, but one of the reasons I picked this job is that I'm learning useful skills that will greatly broaden my prospects for future employment. That means I absolutely want to list this job and the project I'm working on in my CV.

Once probation ends, a harsh post-contractual non-compete clause will kick in, so staying longer would only really be worth it if I stay significantly longer.

Answer (score 3):

Read your contract to be sure *your* probation period does not contain something special. In general there is no difference between you being in your probation and having finished it when looking for a new job. Obviously, you have a shorter notice period.

Sorry this answer is somewhat short, but there is not more to say.

Answer (score 2):

It would be great if you still had some interviews scheduled before you accepted the current position. In this case just wouldn't mention you have already started a new job.

If you decide to start searching a new position within the first 2 months after starting the current I wouldn't mention that you are currently working if I were you.

Otherwise just say the truth - that you like your current tasks but the culture is different to what you expected. Be prepared to answer very precise questions concerning that however. I'm currently looking for a new job after spending 2/3 of a year in a horrible work culture and I'm still treated with suspicion. Germany is very conservative when it comes to that.

Also during job interviews with new companies, try to sell it more as "I want to work for you" and not as "I don't want to work for my current company".